# Are there differences between Google Docs as a standalone vs. when it's included in Google Apps?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

I started using Google Docs and I like it a lot for simple documents and spreadsheets I collaborate on. I still use Word/PowerPoint/Excel for the heavy lifting. I'm using Outlook with Exchange Online for email and I'm happy with it.

Now my question is: will I get more out of Google Docs if I pay for Google Apps? I have a small team so the price doesn't bother me, but since I'm not interested in Google Sites, Calendar or Mail, I wonder what benefit is there for the Google Docs user like me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use Google Docs with Google Apps (the free version), and they are practically identical. There are a few marginal benefits:

- You can set all documents to be shared within your team by default
- You can block users from sharing documents outside your team

There are also some drawbacks:

- New features often take a while to be available in the Google Apps version of Google Docs
- You cannot transfer ownership of a document to someone outside your team (this one has bitten me a few times)

If you already own a domain name, and you don't need more than 10 accounts for your team, you can [try Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html) for free.